# Compatibility error with React Native - the whole error here

Tags: java, react-native, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

my java version in my system is 1.8.0
gradle version is 8.4
kotlin is 1.9.0
Groovy is 3.0.17

now the read the whole error which I am getting whether I run ./gralew clean or ./gradlew assembleDebug
or npm run android is
this -- understand carefully  then offer your suggestion

```
Building app...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'expobareworkflow'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
      > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.
        Searched in the following locations:
          - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.4/gradle-8.4.pom 
          - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.4/gradle-8.4.pom    
        Required by:
            project :
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin.
        Required by:
            project :
         > No matching variant of project :gradle-plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.4' but:
             - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.4')      
             - Variant 'mainSourceElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)      
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.4')      
                     - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)
             - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.4')      
             - Variant 'testResultsElementsForTest' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)      
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.4')      
                     - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)
BUILD FAILED in 2m 12s
Error: E:\React_native\expo_bare_workflow\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You use Gradle plugins that require that you run Gradle at least with Java 11, but you are running Gradle with Java 8. Use a newer Java version to run Gradle and it will work properly, but stay within the bounds of https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html.